# Google Map addListener is not working on zoom-in / zoom-out

Tags: java, google-maps, event-handling, listener, gis

My Requirement is that, in the google map, while someone will click on the zoom-in (+) or Zoom-out (-) button, the locations of all the visible markers will be listed in a div. I used the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    // do something
});
```

But this is working only while the page is loading, but not working while someone clicks on zoom-in (+) or Zoom-out (-) button

Please help me, how this issue can be fixed.

Comment: Well, you don't want 'idle', you want 'zoom_changed'.  Check out the Google Maps events https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en

Comment: For me the idle-listener works as expected when I use the zoom-buttons. Please provide a demo of the issue, maybe your idle-callback doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The better option is to capture the state of the marker just after zoom changes and not at the idle state.

Comment: Thanks For Your Suggestions.
Actually, I need the same functionality like
http://jsfiddle.net/glafarge/mbuLw/
Please Click on zoom-in (+) or zoom-out (-) button.
I want to implement this functionality with wordpress, with unlimited markers and while zooming, I don't know which markers are there in the map.
Please help me, how it can be implemented. Thank You again.